# Having trouble trying to sort double from .txt file

Tags: java, sorting

Trying to sort the doubles in descending order from my .txt file and print out the results, but why am I getting 4 lines of []?

My text file looks like this:

```js
Mary Me,100.0
Hugh More,50.8
Jay Zee,85.0
Adam Cop,94.5
```

with my code that looks like this:

```js
 public static void sortGrade() throws IOException
 {
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("Grades.txt"));

  while(input.hasNextLine())
  {
      String line = input.nextLine();

         ArrayList<Double> grades = new ArrayList<Double>();

         Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
         scan.useDelimiter(",");
         while(scan.hasNextDouble())
         {
          grades.add(scan.nextDouble());
         }
         scan.close();
      Collections.sort (grades,Collections.reverseOrder());   
      System.out.println(grades);
     }
     input.close();
 }
```

I'd like for the output to look like this:

```js
Hugh More,50.8
Jay Zee,85.0
Adam Cop,94.5
Mary Me,100.0
```

A push in the right direction would be great, thanks.

Comment: Create a class with two fields, 'name' and 'grade'. Have your class implement 'Comparable' to sort based on grade. As you read each line from the file, create an instance of your class and add it to an ArrayList. Then call Collections.sort() to sort the list.

Comment: @dnault Is that the only option? I'm not familiar with how to use Comparable yet.

Comment: Not, it's not the only option. What other tools has your instructor told you about? Why not be your own instructor, and read the Javadoc for Comparable: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: @dnault We've only just covered reading files,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not reading in your values correctly!

You're reading in your line here:

```
String line = input.nextLine();
```

And then trying to parse it with a second one but this:

```
scan.hasNextDouble()
```

Will always return `false` as the first token in each string is the name! And it's not a double. You need to change the way you're parsing your input.

Furthermore if you want to sort both the name and the score at the same time you have to create an object that would encapsulate both `name` and `grade` and implement `Comparable` or write a custom `Comparator` for that type. Otherwise you'd have to make a `Map` mapping `grade` to each name, sort the grades and then print it in order while getting names for each grade (there can be multiple names for the same grade). This is not recommended because it does look clumsy.

Writing a comparable class really isn't that hard you just need to implement one method :-)

@Edit: you don't need a second scanner, if your format is set and that easy just use a `split` on that `line` like this:

```
String[] gradeName = line.split(",");
grades.add(Double.parseDouble(gradeName[1]));
```

If you can have more than 1 grade per person than instead of just getting `gradeName[1]` iterate over `gradeName` starting from the element at index `1` (since `0` is the name).

@Edit2:

You are creating a new `grades` list in the loop every time, so it will read one entry, add it to the list, sort it and print it. You should pull out everything except for those lines outside the while loop:

```
String line = input.nextLine();
String[] gradeName = line.split(",");
grades.add(Double.parseDouble(gradeName[1]));
```

@Edit3:

If you want an ascending order don't use `Collections.reverseOrder()`, just the default one:

```
Collections.sort (grades);
```

Comment: should I use `scan.next()`  to can the line then then `Double.parseDouble(line);`  to parse the double from the line?